# One leg of ticket cancelled, other leg disappeared online

Tags: bookings, covid-19, cancellations, turkish-airlines

I am going from Los Angeles to Istanbul and then to Tehran. Turkish airline flight has been canceled to Tehran. When I am going to reschedule my ticket, it only shows that I have 1 flight (Istanbul to Tehran), and I can cancel it. Nothing about my flight from LA to Turkey.

I booked this through an agency which has now gone out of business due to covid.

Does anyone know why this has happened and what I can do to check my other flight is still there?

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Turkish Airlines?

Comment: The phone I am trying to call is 800-874-8875. No operator to answer my call. Could not find any online chat. I tried the video call service. Also, no answer

Comment: Are you in the US? I just tried that 800 number, and it was answered by a voicemail tree. Their office may be closed, both because it's now evening, and also because in the US this is a holiday weekend because Labor Day is on Monday. Try calling again during daytime on Tuesday, Sept, 8.

Comment: Thank you. It was saying that it is 24/7 services, So I skipped the fact that It is a holiday.

Comment: "24/7" might refer to to the automated voicemail, and not to actual humans.

Comment: It's presumably showing only the 1 flight because it says "flights to be checked," and the LAX-IST flight is not one "to be checked" (because it's not cancelled). I agree you'll need to get in touch with them, possibly tomorrow if they're open during daylight hours; it would be pretty strange for a major world airline to just not answer the phone for days, though COVID-related precautions have impacted a lot of customer service operations

Comment: Did you book directly with Turkish or through a third party like Expedia ?

Comment: Thank you. I bought it from an airline agency where is out of the business now in Iran due to Corona virus,

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution to this that you could post as an anwer?

Comment: I called the airline, and they changed the ticket. They accept that the agency in Iran is now closed, and I cannot change the ticket through them

Answer (score 2):

From OP in comments:

> I called the airline, and they changed the ticket. They accept that
> the agency in Iran is now closed, and I cannot change the ticket
> through them